# Product URL Key still existing

Tags: magento-enterprise, product-urls

I change the URL Key of one of my product in my magento store when I try to access the old one, I can still access it. How can I delete the duplicate one?

Thanks!

example:

```
http://mymagentostore/old-product
```

changed to

```
http://mymagentostore/new-product
```

I can still access the /old-product

Comment: Please mark the answer accepted if it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Alyssa, you can remove old redirect in Magento admin backend in `Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management`. Try to filter grid by entering your old URL key in Request Path field.

If you use Magento 1.13 or newer, this grid is accessible in `Catalog -> URL Redirects`.